# How to obtain VisitorToken from RocketChat server

Tags: rocket.chat

In order to Retrieve a LiveChat Message, REST API requires Visitor Token as one of query parameters. In the documentation, I'm unable to find any hint for generating/obtaining visitor token.

[image]

[image]

How to obtain visitor token from Rocket Chat server using any API or any documentation regarding this would be of great help?

Answer (score 1):

You can first create the visitor using this API: https://developer.rocket.chat/reference/api/rest-api/endpoints/omnichannel/livechat-endpoints/visitor/register-a-new-livechat-visitor

If you do not provide a token at this initial payload, one will be created and return to you.

With the token in hands, you can go ahead and create a new Livechat Room, using this endpoint:
https://developer.rocket.chat/reference/api/rest-api/endpoints/omnichannel/livechat-endpoints/livechat-room/livechat-room-info

Now, if you already have a registered visitor, you can search for it using this other endpoint:
https://developer.rocket.chat/reference/api/rest-api/endpoints/omnichannel/livechat-endpoints/visitor/search-for-visitors

Feel free to drop by our [Support Channel](https://open.rocket.chat/channel/support)

:)

Hope this will help you or others.